# Amazon S3 Java SDK & Jackson Strange Exception at production

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, exception, amazon-s3, jackson

I am using Amazon S3 to put files in a bucket which seems to work fine when I am connecting from my localhost. When deployed, I get a strange exception which I cannot explain. I have searched the forums and tried out all recommendations but it doesnt solve my problem. I have even downgraded my jackson annotations and core to different versions with no solution. Have in mind I am able to connect to the Amazon service and upload files if I am running from my local host....here is my full stackTrace

```
StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.enable([Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser$Feature;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;
        at com.amazonaws.partitions.PartitionsLoader.<clinit>(PartitionsLoader.java:54)
        at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionMetadataFactory.create(RegionMetadataFactory.java:30)
        at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.initialize(RegionUtils.java:66)
        at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegionMetadata(RegionUtils.java:54)
        at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegion(RegionUtils.java:107)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.createSigner(AmazonS3Client.java:3288)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3984)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1570)
        at com.jajitech.web.xdata.amazon.s3.AmazonS3Storage.storeToMediaBucket(AmazonS3Storage.java:47)
        at com.jajitech.web.xdata.saver.Saver.insertEntry(Saver.java:267)
        at com.jajitech.web.xdata.saver.Saver.saveEntry(Saver.java:163)
        at org.apache.jsp.saveEntry_jsp._jspService(saveEntry_jsp.java:53)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

Comment: Is it possible that one of your dependencies (i.e. the aws sdk) is using different version of jackson and its being overridden and cause the `NoSuchMethodException`? Try to explicitly put the jackson dependency before all other dependencies, and check it.

Comment: Check your set region in the production by `aws configure` command and verify it with your localhost one

Comment: thanks guys @Avihoo I did that and it still didnt work,,,,,@User528491 I created the bucket manually and i used the client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)); because that was the region I specified during bucket creation. What am I supposed to do if they are different?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I eventually got it to work. As Avhoo had rightly mentioned, it had to do with dependencies. I created a new maven project and just moved my source files into it. I add updated the pom.xml file and let maven download the required libraries. It worked fine since then.